# How to append items to JSON file without parsing and rewriting

Tags: android, json, gson

I am generating Observation objects and want to add them to a json file. The way I'm doing it now, I'm parsing existing file and converting it to JSON object, then adding a new Observation instance to the retrieved collection, parsing it back to JSON and re-writing the file.

Here's my code:

```
final File file = getFile();
final ObservationSet observationSet = retrievePreviousObservations(file);

observationSet.getObservations().add(observation[0]);

final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(GsonHelper.toJson(observationSet).getBytes());
os.close();
```

...

```
private ObservationSet retrievePreviousObservations(final File file) {
    ObservationSet observationSet = new ObservationSet();
    try {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        observationSet = GsonHelper.getGson().fromJson(br, ObservationSet.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No previous file found, this is the first entry", e);
    }
    return observationSet;
}
```

The problem is, that the Observation objects are quite big and after several tens of entries, this appending process takes really long time (generally more than 10 seconds for 20+ items in the collection).

**Is there a way to append to existing JSON file without having to parse the existing one, adding the object, parsing it back and rewriting the file?**

Comment: Perhaps the right answer is to not use JSON for this task. Either use a file format that is more amenable to appending (e.g., CSV) or use a data engine that can handle incremental updates (e.g., SQLite). In principle, appending to a JSON array as a file could be as simple as deleting the trailing `]`, appending the new JSON object (with appropriate comma), and appending the trailing `]` back to make the JSON legit. However, whether there is an existing library that will do this for you, I can't say.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was considering that appending manually option. Might even write such library myself. Thanks for your input!